# Using own Application class in ZF2

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have been playing with my own `MyApplication` class (extending `Zend\Mvc\Application`) in ZF2.

In `index.php` I use

```
MyApplication::init(
   // here goes system config...
)->run();
```

One essential problem with this is that ServiceManager will still set `Zend\Mvc\Application` as the 'Application' service.

I noticed that in `Zend\Mvc\Service\ServiceListenerFactory` where the default `Application` factory is defined, there is a note that this default MVC-related service configuration can be overridden by modules. I was playing with it but was not able to make my `MyApplication` instance as the `'Application'` service.

I am using ZF2 version 2.2.6. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: It's unclear what you have tried already - Ideally you would need to change just the *factory* not the service name. So in your `module.config.php` add a factory `'Application' => 'MyModule\Service\MyApplicationFactory'`.

Comment: I was trying to set it up like you say, but with lower case initial a, i.e. 'application'. I was getting an error saying `'A service by the name or alias "application" already exists and cannot be overridden`. My mistake.